# how to add line above tabs android tablayout

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

need help

I have searched for my requirement but didn't found so posting my own question.

I need to show line above tabs not below as all solution is for adding the line below the tabs text.

[image]

should I use custom tabs or android supports this scenario without making custom ??

links I have viewed are as follows

https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=fabric+documentation&rlz=1C1CHBD_enPK741PK753&oq=fabric+documentation+&aqs=chrome..69i57.5669j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=how+to+adding+line+above+tabs+android

no code is posted as I want to know what should be used .. ur suggestion would be helpful .. thanks

Comment: I do not know the best solution but I recommend creating a custom view for tabs with the line on top.

Comment: ok thanks will try  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this  create a background in `res/drawable` folder and set `app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector"`

**make your like this Tablayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/selector" />
```

Here **selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:top="3dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
                    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="2dp"/>

                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:top="3dp" android:left="-5dp" android:right="-5dp" android:bottom="-5dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
                    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:width="2dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Hope it will works if not then add comment.

Comment: thanks a tons  buddy u saved my time .. working like a charm ..
it would be great if u explain a little how its done ..

Comment: yes in this i applied tab background in which it create new view using layer list and using state it apply line

Comment: done.. kindly can u tell how to do this kinda task in future

Comment: just try to understand concept and read documentation provide for android in official site

Comment: yes bro but how ? i mean like i had this situation .. how would i search for in documentation

Comment: find property of widget or attribute of widget given in documentation that will help to problem i also search for whole 1 day and then i made solution.

Comment: how to increase the height of the line there is no tab indicator for it ??

Comment: how to increase its height .? @PriteshVadhiya

Comment: @atif in selector change width as you want it will change height of it

Answer (score 0):

```
app:tabIndicatorGravity="top"
```

Its very simple now to show the indicator at the top with this.